# copy one column from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am confused about how to copy a column from one table to another table using where. I wrote SQL query but it says transaction lock time exceeded or query returns more than one row.
using mysql
Basically,
I have:

```
Table 1:  Results
BuildID  platform_to_insert

Table 2:  build
BuildID correct_platform

update results set results.platform_to_insert 
     = (select correct_platform from  
       build where results.BuildID = build.BuildID)
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in each table? Show us the complete and actual error message that MySQL gives you

Comment: the way you have written your query can indeed return more than one row from the subselect: which value of correct_platform should be taken if more than one exists for a given buildID?

Comment: what I want to do is : for each BuildID from results, compare it with BuildID in build is same, then take that correct_platform from build and insertinto platform_to_insert in Results

Comment: why doesnt this work?   
update results R
set R.correct_platform_in_results_table = B.correct_platform
inner join build B
on R.BuildID=B.BuildID

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I do not believe you need a sub query.

```
UPDATE results, build
SET    results.platform_to_insert = build.correct_platform
WHERE  results.BuildID = build.BuildID
```

Comment: Wow, awesome answer. This fundamentally changes my understanding of relational databases

Comment: Hii i have tried this query but not working properly pls check : UPDATE staff_login_times, staff_rotas
SET    staff_login_times.scheduled_start  = staff_rotas.startdate
WHERE  staff_login_times.actual_start = staff_rotas.startdate;

Answer (score 5):

There are two options here:

1. update your tables to use `BuildID` as a primary key (to avoid duplicates)
2. update your subquery to only return one result

   ```
   UPDATE results SET results.platform_to_insert = (
       SELECT correct_platform
       FROM build
       WHERE results.BuildID=build.BuildID LIMIT 1
   );
   ```

Comment: the problem is that the WHERE clause is matching multiple elements in the subquery.  This can be solved by limiting the subquery's result set to one or making *.BuildID a primary key to avoid duplicates in the first place.

In either case all of the rows will be updated.

Comment: I have executed query as per your suggestion but query is not executing will you please help me my post is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59064755/copy-column-from-one-table-to-another-table-but-hangs-db-browser-for-sqlite