# Copy data from one column to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table **A**

```
col-PK  col2  col3   col4
1       a      aa     aaa
2       b      bb     bbb
```

I have created a new table **B** with three columns only

```
col-PKB  colOne  ColTwo
```

I want below as the **Final Output**

**Table A**

```
col-PK  col2  col3   col4
1       a      aa     aaa
2       b      bb     bbb
```

**Table B**

```
col-PKB  colOne  ColTwo  
1       a       aa     
2       b       bb
```

Solution I looked into [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015527/copy-one-column-from-one-table-to-another). But I think I need to use `select` statement as I have `multiple columns` to copy. Please guide me here. I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO` with a `SELECT`-query of the columns you want to add:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col-PKB, colOne, ColTwo)
  SELECT
    col-PK,
    col2,
    col3
  FROM tableA;
```

Comment: I checked the documentation and there is one SELECT INTO clause. Is that not what I need. Just wondering.

Comment: Of course you can also use `SELECT col-PK, col2, col3 INTO tableB FROM tableA`. But this creates a new tableB. The new table will be created with the column-names and types as defined in the `SELECT` statement. You can apply new names using the `AS` clause. But if you already created one like in your question, use `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: I already have the table with all the columns created into it. So I guess I am better off with your original answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Accepting the answer would be appreciated then,

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column)
  SELECT a_column 
  FROM a_table
```

In your case,

```
INSERT INTO tableB (
col-PKB, colOne, ColTwo
)
SELECT col-PK, col2, col3 
FROM tableA
```