# Copy column from one table to another table but it hangs DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to copy one table's column to another table's column with where condition that both employee id should be equal, more than 300k records.

below is my query

```
UPDATE emp SET emp.address = (
    SELECT emp_address
    FROM address
    WHERE emp.emp_id=address.emp_id LIMIT 1
);
```

I have executed this query since last 1 hour but still process is going on, I have executed this query on "DB  Browser for SQLite".

Am I making any mistake? or there is problem with sqlite browser?

Comment: What i can suggest is to check if `emp.address` has any indexes if yes drop them. And check `address.emp_id` if has any indexes if no add one. If it is still taking long you can add a temporary field to use as flag for update and try to update your database in chunks. Or you can try increase the page and cache size and turn off journal.

Comment: There was a index on emp.emp_id, right now I have deleted and executed query let me check if it is working or not

Comment: No you shouldn't delete it. It will slow your look up time. Delete indexes only the ones you are executing update on the column.

Comment: I have tried with both way with delete and without delete but it's not working, I have waited till 1.5 hours but nothing happens, so I have quit

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
UPDATE emp
    SET emp.address = (SELECT a.emp_address
                       FROM address a
                       WHERE e.emp_id = a.emp_id 
                       LIMIT 1
                      );
```

You want an index on `address(emp_id, emp_address)`.

An index on `emp(emp_id)` should not be used by this query and is not useful.  If you have an index on `emp(address)`, you might want to drop it and recreate it after the update.

All that said, you are updating *all* records in the table.  This is expensive.

It is often faster to recreate the table.  Something like this:

```
create table temp_emp as 
    select . . . ,  -- all columns except address
           (select a.emp_address
            from address a
            where e.emp_id = a.emp_id 
            limit 1
           ) as address
    from emp;

truncate table emp;   -- backup the data first!

insert into emp ( . . . )  -- list the columns here
    select . . .
    from temp_temp;
```

You can create the temporary table and see how long that takes (with the above mentioned index).  The truncate and `insert` should not take very long.  But do backup the data first!

Comment: will definitely check it and let you know thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know but sqlite might not support it I am getting an error like Result: near "as": syntax error
At line 1:
CREATE TABLE TEMP_EMP as SELECT (

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit . . . SQLite supports this syntax:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html.